# Relative @imports break ng-packagr with error "returned value of `file` must be a string"

Tags: ng-packagr

We recently updated our Angular Dependencies to 6, and now ng-packagr breaks with the listed error. with ng serve and ng build, the import strategy...

```
@import "~src/scss/variables"
```

works fine. When ng packagr gets to the Rendering Stylesheets portion, it breaks with the error above.
This is my ng-package.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
    "lib": {
        "entryFile": "public_api.ts",
        "externals": {
            "@angular/animations": "ng.animations"
        }
    },
    "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": ["."]
}
```

Is there an option I'm missing?

Comment: I've dug into the build dependencies to figure out why it's not resolving to the right directory. I found that its taking the route `@import "~src/scss/variables"` and appending it to my component directory like ... `/Users/myuser/projectdir/src/component/~src/scss/variables`

Comment: Did you find an actual fix for this? This keeps coming up for me when I switch branches and won't go away until I navigate through the entire branch commit tree, which is really tedious.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I had to revert to just using a relative path-ing scheme.

Comment: I found a solution for my code, which was that I was working in an Angular 6 library and was importing a file in the library that didn't exist _until_ the library was built. Fixing that import resolved the error for me.